# Checking whether a class name exists?

Tags: jquery

I want to check whether a class name exist irrespective of its id or tag.

Suppose I'm having class name "temp".

I need to check something like `jQuery('.temp').length` -> this is not working

Comment: Can you post your HTML?  What you have provided as the jQuery should work.  See [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/VNajQ/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){
    return jQuery(this).length>0;
}

if ($(selector).exists()) {
    // Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.temp').length` does work.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/wEXVu/

Comment: sorry i made a mistake i didnt put '. ' . This also give same result $('.temp').size()